# how could you use array for unit conversion of 4 different units

Tags: arrays, function, input, procedure, break

Based off the user’s selection accept a number from the user to be entered as that unit. Both
integer (eg 1) and floating-point numbers (eg 1.23) should be accepted. Ask the user to select which unit they wish the result to be in. The options are (pounds)ib,(ounces)oz,(short ton)st and (tonnes)T. Based off the user’s selection, convert the number they entered into the appropriate unit and
display it to the user correct to two decimal places. Ask the user if they would like to continue by entering the character ‘c’ or exit by entering the character ‘e’. If continue is selected, the program should repeat from just after displaying the welcome message. If exit is selected, the program should end, and an appropriate message should be displayed.

I tried using array with NumPy but I didn't know the format therefore i would like your help it would be great as it is entered to my final mark

Comment: Look, this site is not for asking people to do your homework for you from scratch, it's for helping you solve problems. Add what you've got so far, and I will be happy to help you with what you aren't sure how to do.